# Reputation not appearing in Rep. Notification Queue - yet it is given silently

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, notifications, achievements-dialog

I [answered a question on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1346687/419485) and while on other sites I did not get a 'Reputation Notification' to explain that I was given 2 upvotes for my answer - yet if I manually check my Profile here at meta.SE my total Reputation is in agreement with the amount there.

I'm not knowledgeable about the intercommunication between the servers and sites but I would explain it this way: Super User either failed to send or other sites failed to receive the *message* the I had a reputation update on Super User.

I should have received either two green star trophies () of 10 reputation each or one of 20; depending on when I returned to one of the Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow / Super User / etc. sites.

Here's a screenshot showing no reputation change notification for Super User:

[image: Meta.SE Reputation Pulldown]

Here's a screenshot of my Profile over at Super User showing that I was silently credited:

[image: My Super User Profile]

I'm bringing this up on Meta.SE in case the communication is broken between more sites than just Super User and everywhere else.

Comment: It's also broken on Meta.SE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpntu.jpg (that's a question from today with 3 upvotes)

Comment: *I'm bringing this up on Meta.SE in case the communication is broken between more sites than just SuperUser and everywhere else.* Confirmed for SO.

Comment: Not only Super User and meta, it is network wide. I asked it in chat first for confirmation. Earned rep is not shown but badges are shown. https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7151328#7151328

Comment: Thanks. Other Rep. Notifications seem to come through, only found one site but I thought there could be many that I'm not registered at.

Comment: The achievements inbox in the app doesn't work either.

Comment: This issue seems to exist on SFF as well, for myself and one other user.

Comment: Effect shown on SFF for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztiyi.png

Comment: I only see awarded badges on every site I visit.

Comment: This also reproduces in the the mobile apps (both the old SE app and the new SO app)

Comment: Possibly related (or should I ask a new question?): A user's site-wide activity page (e.g. https://stackexchange.com/users/2397966/tripehound?tab=activity) doesn't seem to be being updated (mine shows my most recent activity as 20 hours ago, but I've done stuff since then).

Comment: @TripeHound I can confirm the wrong behavior of the “global” activity page.

Comment: This issue is site wide on SE. The achievement icon isn't showing any activity, if you drill down to your reputation section of your profile it's getting updated though.

Comment: In case they are different issues, I've created a separate question [Site-wide activity page not being updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313728/213468) for the problem I saw.

Comment: This problem is also appear at Math.SE, I posted same question on Math.meta.SE yesterday: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28827/reputation-change-doesnt-appear-in-the-feed?noredirect=1#comment121367_28827

Comment: Seems it might just have sprung back into life... I've just got notification of upvotes on the possibly-related problem with the site-wide activity page (and that seems fixed as well).

Comment: It's fixed now, see [answer from Nick Craver](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372137/1663001) on SO.

Comment: @TripeHound - I have *some*, but let's have someone test if everywhere is working.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was an issue with the aggregator. Now fixed, and data that was queued (none should be lost) will be coming in over the next ~20 minutes (estimate, may be longer). [Original answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372137/13249).

Comment: Presumably that also explains [Site-wide activity page not being updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313728/213468) which also sprung back into life at the same time. Should I close that as a duplicate of this question?

Comment: I confirm that the info is "dribbling in", now.

Comment: Seems to work, thanks for solving it!

Comment: Did this perhaps fix [my bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313699/295232) as well?

Comment: Again, the achievements pop-up does not show the recent changes (seen on Stack Overflow and on Math Stack Exchange).

Comment: Agreed, MartinR. My reputation gains here aren't showing up.

Comment: Fixed, again. Thanks. BTW: There was an approximately 5 hour delay between earning and notification.