# Site-wide activity page not being updated

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, network-profile, recent-activity

*This may or may not be linked with the problem described in [Reputation not appearing in Rep. Notification Queue - yet it is given silently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313701/213468) (which is apparently site-wide, not just on Super User).*

The site-wide activity page (`https://stackexchange.com/users/USER-NUMBER/USER-NAME?tab=activity`) which shows a summary of one's activity across all Stack Exchange sites seems not to be being updated.

> I'm having trouble uploading an example image (imgur is rejecting the request): you can get to the page by clicking the icon/reputation/badges element in the top menu, then the *Network Profile* link to the top-right and then selecting the *Activity* tab.

My page shows my last activity as 22 hours ago, although I have answered at least one question and made a number of comments since then.

Comment: Ha, I was just about to report this. Here's a randomly-picked example: [network activity](https://stackexchange.com/users/35417/martijn-pieters?tab=activity) is missing a lot of [site activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters?tab=activity).

Comment: Looks like it may have just got fixed... the page has just updated. The linked topic also (I just got notification of the upvotes on this question).

Comment: Same in *StackOverflow en español* (spanish version)