# When is the network wide rep graph updated?

Tags: support, reputation, network-profile

For a couple of days now, I have been getting some reputation on 200+ rep sites, and I want to be able to see the reputation in my network-wide graph. However, even past 0:00 UTC, sometimes, the network wide rep graph is not updated. When, in absolute time, is the network-wide rep graph updated?

Comment: It actually depends on the time or analytics.

Comment: There are two timeslots I know off when infrequent batch job are run: 0:00 UTC and 03:00 UTC. Some batch jobs don't run daily but on a less frequent schedule. So in this case it might take 48 hours between an reputation change event on your profile and the actual run of the job that updates the graph.

Comment: Sometimes, never. Similar complaints: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299601/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313728/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285563/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323284/282094