# Reputation changes not visible in the achievement box

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, achievements-dialog

I earned 38 reputation on Movies & TV today at the time of writing this question. However the achievement box doesn't reflect so.

[image]

[image]

As we can see in the first image, there are three positive and two negative reputation changes, but the box, as in second image, only shows one positive and one negative.

The reputation score in the header changes, though.

Comment: FWIW, badge notifications do work at the moment.

Comment: @Glorfindel Didn't earn any today though, so couldn't tell.

Comment: It's happening to me too at the moment. Similar to [an issue that happened 3 years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297483/reputation-not-showing-up-in-the-achievements-tab-anymore)

Comment: Similar bug which occurred a month ago [Reputation not appearing in Rep. Notification Queue - yet it is given silently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313701/357396)

Comment: Looks like we have to ping Nick Craver. :P

Comment: @AJ [Martin R did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313701/reputation-not-appearing-in-rep-notification-queue-yet-it-is-given-silently#comment1034992_313732)

Comment: Got a ping on this and I see the cause - we'll get a fix out ASAP.

Comment: Same here. Got +10rep ~1h ago on SOru. Don't see it in achievements box.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A new type of error we hadn't seen before propagating chat moderator events got jammed up in the queue after a race with an account merge. A fix by Marc Gravell has been built out and we're watching the aggregator queue drain now.

All should be back to normal in about 10-20 minutes.

Comment: Seems like it is working now.

Comment: It seems to have broke again.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same as of now