# Reputation changes not visible in the achievement box (again)

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, achievements-dialog

Just like [yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315836/reputation-changes-not-visible-in-the-achievement-box), which was marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). But today, it's not working again. I'm still notified of new badges:

[image]

[image]

**Update:** it looks like new events are now updated; reputation events from earlier this UTC afternoon are still missing:

[image]

Comment: Something changed between 11:44 and 12:02 UTC today.

Comment: Yeh, same here =/

Comment: same thing happening to me

Comment: It's certainly confusing me...

Comment: This [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBSww.png) is what I see.

Comment: Just got a +x from an upvote that wasn't reported... now I'm getting all notifications that I didnt get before

Comment: I just got a rep notification for a new event.  Missed events are still missing and the total is still wrong.  (Those might just be gone, but at least it looks like things are flowing again.)

Comment: This issue on Meta.SO: [“Recent Achievements” popup/badge is not updating](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374534/4642212).

Comment: So.... Seems that this issue is gone to right? Anybody else still experiencing them?

Comment: @DarkCygnus no further problems here...

Comment: New instance of this issue? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316336/332286

Comment: Irony: This is now status-completed status-completed. Let's hope it doesn't need to be status-completed status-completed status-completed.

Comment: This is happening again. See TL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of right now, I am starting to get all the notifications that weren't notified before, one by one... perhaps this suggests that this bug is now in the verge of getting fixed (again?).

The total rep is still off, but I'm starting to get more and more notifications now:

[image]

**Update:** New rep changes I get are notified immediately now (like the ones from this answer). Also, my total rep is now up-to-date; my TWP rep on the achievements bar now matches the rep I made today ([202](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/73791/darkcygnus?tab=reputation)):

[image]

Comment: Yes, it seems so (see the update to my question).

Comment: @Glorfindel the UV you just gave me was notified instantly BTW :)