# Some network profiles show 0 badges for CS50

Tags: bug, badges, network-profile

[My account list](https://stackexchange.com/users/6085540/glorfindel?tab=accounts) shows that I didn't earn any badges on [CS50](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/), but [that's not true](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/users/15210/glorfindel?tab=badges).

[image]

CS50 *is* a special site, in that it's in perpetual private beta, but not so special that the network aggregator can't determine the number of badges. It's even capable of doing that for Area 51 which runs on a really old version of the Stack Exchange platform. Also, it used to work properly, as can be seen from e.g. [this Wayback Machine copy](http://web.archive.org/web/20200422113142/https://stackexchange.com/users/6085540/glorfindel?tab=accounts).

[image]

Not everybody is affected by this bug, [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/5682591/cliff-b?tab=accounts) is the network profile of the top user at CS50 and for him, the badges are shown. However, [one of the moderators](https://stackexchange.com/users/4585593/curiouskiwi?tab=accounts) is affected.

Comment: In addition to CS50 we are [also affected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6CT1.png) on [Cardano](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/users/40/glorfindel?tab=topactivity) where it's clear you've had a number of badges for a while, but the [aggregator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313701/282094) is plugged up there too.

Comment: I'm also showing up as having 0 badges on CS50 even though I have a couple badges.