# Why does the accounts tab on the network profile show my CS50 account with 1 rep instead of 101?

Tags: bug, reputation, network-profile

If I scroll to the bottom of [my network account's accounts tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/5129611/mithical?tab=accounts), I can see that it shows my [CS50.SE](https://cs50.stackexchange.com) account as having 1 rep:

[image: screenshot showing the cs50 profile on the accounts tab with 1 reputation]

However, if I actually go to the site, my profile says I have 101 reputation (because of the association bonus):

[image: screenshot of my cs50 profile, showing the site name and 101 reputation]

Why is there this discrepancy? Why isn't the association bonus being registered for viewing the account on the accounts tab, but is registered if I actually visit the site?

Comment: Is your suspension still caching?

Comment: @rene - I don't believe I've ever been suspended there (or anywhere), so I'd certainly hope not :P

Comment: There more wrong with CS50 in that list: [Some network profiles show 0 badges for CS50](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359110/295232)