# Badge count on Flair lower than last week

Tags: support, bug, badges, combined-flair

I seem to have lost a gold badge and five bronze badges, while gaining one silver, after the latest update of my [Flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/flair/info).

Here are the last five updates of my Flair:

- June 29 2022:
  [image: Flair 56 282 768]
- June 24 2022:
  [image: Flair 57 281 773]
- June 17 2022:
  [image: Flair 57 281 772]
- June 12 2022:
  [image: Flair 57 281 769]
- June 08 2022:
  [image: Flair 57 281 767]

and here are my last Achievements notifications:

> [image: Achievements Notifications]

I've only gained badges, not lost any reputation (causing a community to fall below 200), yet I have fewer badges than I did the week before.

Here's a screenshot of my [Network Profile Badge Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELcNb.png) tab.

Here is an independent count using [rene's](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/11779/rene) SEDE query "[Badge count across the network to match what is in your flair](https://data.stackexchange.com/freelancing/query/898502/badge-count-across-the-network-to-match-what-is-in-your-flair#resultSets)" I see: 57 , 287 , and 782  badges ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDIVb.png)).

Was there a [recalculation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372137/3648282) or a [problem with the Aggregator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313701/282094) ?

---

This currently appears to have been corrected:

- June 31 2022:
  [image: Flair 57 283 774]

The SEDE query still says: 57 , 287 , and 782 , which is expected, as it won't update for a day and a half; and always differs from the Flair (and Area 51 totals).

---

A few people have put forth a theory that a temporary loss of [tag-badges](/questions/tagged/tag-badges) has resulted in a lowering of the badge counts on my [combined-flair](/questions/tagged/combined-flair).

I disagree with this for a few reasons:

- The criteria for Tag Badges are as follows:

  These badges are awarded for participating in non community-wiki questions with particular tags. If enough votes are earned in a tag with 100+ total questions, the badge will be automatically created and awarded.

  Gold Tag Badge -
  You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

  Silver Tag Badge -
  You must have a total score of 400 in at least 80 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

  Bronze Tag Badge -
  You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

To obtain a gold tag badge I would need 10,000 reputation on one tag (plus the other criteria).

I only have over 10K reputation on this site, but [no gold tag badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/282094/rob?tab=tags) (dupehammer). I'm also a fair distance away from converting my bronze tag badges to silver.

I don't have enough reputation or posts to have previously held the tag badges that would need to be lost to lower my totals.

Here are my tag scores:

[image: Profile - Tag scores]

- The combined flair always shows an increasing number of badges, none have ever been taken away over the past couple of years.

Here are the downloaded flair for the past two years, over 80 times it has always increased; for the *tag badge theory* to be correct I'd simply never have lost a tag badge for the past two years (except for two days ago).

[image: Combined flair for the past two years.]

I'm just reporting an apparent bug or abnormality, as we are asked to; if it's not investigated or repaired I'm OK with that, it's not my computer.

Comment: Integer overflow?

Comment: Probably a tag badge getting revoked. Those get revoked when you no longer meet their criteria.

Comment: That's not how it's calculated.

Comment: Check for deleted answers. The most likely case is old question (90 days at least) getting deleted, and your answer deleted alongside it as well, with score of 3 or more. The reputation is kept, you don't get any notification, however if this drops you below gold tag badge criteria, as Sonic said, the badge would just disappear, as if it never existed.

Comment: @sha, Tag badges have nothing to do with this.

Comment: @Shad don't confuse https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/flair/info with https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/tag-score/info - if this had anything to do with tags it would be tagged with https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-badges/info - see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tags/info

Comment: Not sure what's with the insistence that tag badges have nothing to do with it. They are included in your total count of badges on each site like the normal badges. If you lost one, your badge count would naturally go down. And there's no notification that you lost one, so it'd be hard to tell if that was the cause or not. It's a logical theory. // We didn't do anything to "fix" this. It's entirely poasible it was just a temporary hiccup where the flair image failed to pull in one of your sites while being generated or some weird race condition.

Comment: @animuson, The reasons for my insistence that "tag badges are not included in your Flair" are: my past experience, rene's query doesn't count them, [this user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317490/3648282) agrees, and as you can see in the question (from the history of my totals) the number ***always*** increased and has never gone lower. Perhaps you are thinking of the:   https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/user-card/info  - I agree with your last sentence, that was my theory offered in my question here: "Was there a recalculation or a problem with the Aggregator ?".

Comment: Tag badges are absolutely included in flair counts. They're not specifically called out in the query because they are stored in almost an identical way to other badges - there's no need to look at them separately. // The aggregator has absolutely nothing to do with flair. That has to do with the achievements populating into the dropdown for users. *shrugs* If it wasn't tag badge revocations, you may never know what caused it.

Comment: @animuson, after the text "Here are the last five updates of my Flair" I show 5 previous Flair, taken over a period of 20 days. I have 50 sites where I have over 200 reputation, that contribute to the Flair total. --- Your theory requires that over the past several years only once, yesterday, did I have a tag badge revoked (even bronze), causing the Flair to be reported as lower than the previous times. --- I have been keeping copies of my Flair for the past two years, each download of the PNG file shows an increase in the number of at least one badge category, no decreases. Seems contrary.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. That's the way they work and it is certainly a possibility. That it seems unlikely to you is not evidence to the contrary. I can't say I really care enough about tiny abnormalities in badge counts on a flair image to spend time investigating it any further. Like I said, you may never know.

Comment: @Rob you could have said earlier "I never had any gold tag badge on any site" instead of the complicated replies you gave. Anyway, at this point looks like there was some temporary glitch somewhere, be it the code generating the flair, or the count stored internally somewhere. But as long as it's not persistent and you don't actually lose badges you rightfully earned, it's really no big deal, and not worth spending staff time on it.

Comment: I like this post, the gif animation is especially cool. In SE terms it's the next best thing to doing a [*"I took a picture everyday"* time-lapse](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=i+took+a+picture+everyday).

Comment: In case it helps, I tried to create a SEDE query which [shows counts of user's tag badges over all sites](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1612107/number-of-tag-badges-of-a-user-per-site?accountid=4485506) - at the time when SEDE was last updated (June 26), the query shows no gold tag badges. (Sorry for two comments - previously I posted a wrong link by mistake.)

Comment: This bug reoccurred recently.